# ASP.NET Docker Build with Azure NuGet feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, devops

I Dockerized a .Net 7 web application letting Visual Studio generate the dockerfile.

When I debug the application from Visual Studio it runs, but when I try to build the image it failed because it wasn't able to locate the packages from nuget.org as some of them are hosted in our Azure NuGet Feed.

I created a nuget.config, added an entry to my Azure NuGet Feed, and added a step to copy it

```
COPY nuget.config .
```

But now the challenge is authenticate it using a Personal Access Token.

I tried using the packageSourceCredentials in the nuget.config file, but is supposed to have a username and password, but I have a token instead, so trying to use it in the password field didn't work.

I tried using the command `nuget sources add` but the command is not installed in the image mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 and I wasn't able to install it in the container following [microsof docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools) for linux.

The error is:
error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source ...

How can I make the docker build succeed using an internal NuGet feed hosted on Azure?